# How to insert UNIQUE IDs values from several tables into events table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a table called `events` defined as follow:

[image]

`rep_id`, `hcp_id`, `brand_id`, `email_id` and `content_id` is the IDs in other tables.

`event_type` should be kind of array containing this values:

```
[
    "rep_login",
    "rep_share",
    "email_viewed",
    "brand_page_opened",
    "media_viewed",
    "rep_contacted",
]
```

I need to insert 10k rows on `events` table but compliance with these conditions:

- Each row should contains UNIQUE values for each column
- `event_type` should be randomize for populate the table with several event types

This data is for testing purpose. Can this be done from MySQL query? How?

Comment: For your table structures, can you please give us a "SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table\G"?  "For Each row should contains UNIQUE values for each column" - just put a UNIQUE index on each one. It's your array structure that's going to be much more difficult. JSON (will be/is in 5.7 I think) **might** be the way to go. You could look at PostgreSQL 9.4 which has JSON support. For further MySQL opinion, could you give some sample data and your desired result and the logic you used to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this insert statement to insert some totally useless data in there (assuming the FK accuracy is not important here) but it satisfies your conditions.

```
    DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Events_insertion$$
CREATE PROCEDURE Events_insertion()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i  INT;
    DECLARE dTime DATETIME;
    SET i = 1;
    SET dTime = NOW();
    WHILE i  <= 10000 DO
       INSERT INTO EVENTS_TEST VALUES
        (
        null,
        (ELT(0.5 + RAND() * 6, "rep_login",
            "rep_share",
            "email_viewed",
            "brand_page_opened",
            "media_viewed",
            "rep_contacted")),
        LAST_INSERT_ID()+2,
        LAST_INSERT_ID()+3,
        LAST_INSERT_ID()+4,
        LAST_INSERT_ID()+5,
        LAST_INSERT_ID()+6,
        (dTime + interval (LAST_INSERT_ID()) second),
        (dTime + interval (LAST_INSERT_ID()) minute)
        );
       SET  i = i + 1; 
    END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You can call this procedure like this

```
call Events_insertion();
```

and also try not to use name events as your table name since it is a reserved word.
Hope this could help you :)

Comment: I have no experience with scripts or stored procedures, can you add that also to your answer? Right now I am trying to get this done from PHP side using a script and doing multiple queries

Comment: i made a stored procedure for it to insert 10K rows (since we don't post PHP codes here)